# What is the the correct way to call a recursive function while using axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

Will this allow me to recursively call an API without running indefinitely?
*** Do I have to return the function or can I just call it within the function?

```
const apiUrl = "https://api.website.com/products";
let productArray = [];
let lowPrice = 0;
let highPrice = 100000;

const countProduct = async (lowPrice, highPrice) => {
  const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {`enter code here`
    params: {
      minPrice: lowPrice,
      maxPrice: highPrice
    }
  });


  let lowerLimit = minPrice;
  let upperLimit = maxPrice;

  while (upperLimit > lowerLimit || response.data.count === 0) {
    if (response.data.count >= 1000) {
        countProduct(lowerLimit, (lowerLimit + upperLimit / 2));  // ***<---  Can I just call the function or do I have to return it 
    } else {
      response.data.products.forEach(product => {
        if (product.price > lowerLimit) { 
          lowerLimit = product.price;
        } 
        productArray.push(product);
      })
      lowerLimit = parseInt(lowerLimit + 0.01);
      upperLimit = parseInt(100000);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: First, `productArray.push(product);` won't work, you're mutating in an async call. As for your actual question, you *really* want to try to avoid doing that if possible, making a bunch of network requests in a loop is problematic. Do your data processing on the backend, or ideally in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  What would you suggest for web scraping?  Already using a premade API and looking for an automated solution.